# Keep view instance in activity or get it everytime?

Tags: android, performance

What's the best practice?

In an activity with a lot of views (hypothetic), should i fill an instance and use it or call the findViewById Everytime?

```
public class AskActivity extends Activity {
    //this
    public EditText question_edit;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //...
        //Or this?
        findViewById(R.id.question_edit);
}
```

Comment: Use findviewbyId once and assign it to a public variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Android studio`, fortunatly, is really smart.

First, if you don't use your `View` outside of the `activity`, change the property to `private` (or whatever) instead of `public`.

Then, as aliaksei said, it depends; there are not best practice.

If you use your view only in one `method`, create a `local variable` with

```
private void myLocalMethod(){
  ...
  View myView = findViewById(R.id.myView);
  ...
}
```

Elseway, if you use your `View` in multple `methods`, create it with `class` `scope`:

```
View myView;

//inside onCreate method, or the first that uses it
...
myView = findViewById(R.id.myView);
// now you can refer to myView anywhere
..
```

Anyway, if you create a View with `class-scope` but you reference it only in one `method`, `Android Studio` will warn you with something like this:

[image]

In any case, don't call `findViewById()` in every `method`, if you reference a `view` in more than one, cast it as `class View`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

`findViewById` is considerably slow call, so yes, store views in variables for future reference as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

They aren't mutually exclusive, you need to do both otherwise if you only do the first one, you will get an NPE anytime you try to use it and similarly with a Inflation Exception for the second one.

Just make sure you actually assign the found view to the EditText variable:

```
question_edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.question_edit);
```